# Mailing system in GoogleSheets, resume of crypto-transactions. I'm notified only about 1 of 7 operations, and more than once. How to edit the script?

Tags: email, google-sheets, notifications, repeat

Actually the code is as follows, there are 7 active operations plus one of the required two sendEmail functions.

Most of this code has been copied from another discussion so not mine, tried to adjust it up to my purpose.

The goal is:
1. get the script to check if a cell on the sheet called AutoMail is empty or filled with either "gain position" or "purchase position" (it's not one cell, there are two, the one on the left is eventually filled with the first expression and on the right with the latter);
2. in case of gain/purchase position, get the relative coin abbreviation and amount from two cells located on another sheet (YourData) and to paste them in a personalized text used as subject and then in the body of my message, and of course let this email reach my inbox, possibly ONCE the cell is filled up with the above mentioned expressions, not every minute.

I'd like the script to check the sheets once every minute, I think I mistake in the trigger setting as well. The repetition of var ss1 and var sheet1 might be useless here.

```
    function readCell() {
      var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName("AutoMail"); 
      var operationgain1 = sheet1.getRange("C2:C46").getValue();
      var operationpurchase1 = sheet1.getRange("D2:D46").getValue();
      var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("YourData");
      var coin1 = sheet2.getRange("B3");
      var amount1 = sheet2.getRange("B4");
      if(operationgain1="gain position") sendEmail(operationgain1);
        function sendEmail(operationgain1) {
          var email = "adrian@semeniuk.biz";
          var subject = "Your "+amount1+" "+coin1+" are somewhere in gain position.";
          var body = "Keep an eye on your "+coin1+"s, they're goin' up.";
          MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,body);}
      var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName("AutoMail"); 
      var operationgain2 = sheet1.getRange("E2:E46").getValue();
      var operationpurchase2 = sheet1.getRange("F2:F46").getValue();
      var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("YourData");
      var coin2 = sheet2.getRange("C3");
      var amount2 = sheet2.getRange("C4");
      if(operationgain2="gain position") sendEmail(operationgain2);
        function sendEmail(operationgain2) {
          var email = "adrian@semeniuk.biz";
          var subject = "Your "+amount2+" "+coin2+" are somewhere in gain position.";
          var body = "Keep an eye on your "+coin2+"s, they're goin' up.";
          MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,body);}
      var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName("AutoMail"); 
      var operationgain3 = sheet1.getRange("G2:G46").getValue();
      var operationpurchase3 = sheet1.getRange("H2:H46").getValue();
      var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("YourData");
      var coin3 = sheet2.getRange("D3");
      var amount3 = sheet2.getRange("D4");
      if(operationgain3="gain position") sendEmail(operationgain3);
        function sendEmail(operationgain3) {
          var email = "adrian@semeniuk.biz";
          var subject = "Your "+amount3+" "+coin3+" are somewhere in gain position.";
          var body = "Keep an eye on your "+coin3+"s, they're goin' up.";
          MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,body);}
      var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName("AutoMail"); 
      var operationgain4 = sheet1.getRange("I2:I46").getValue();
      var operationpurchase4 = sheet1.getRange("J2:J46").getValue();
      var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("YourData");
      var coin4 = sheet2.getRange("E3");
      var amount4 = sheet2.getRange("E4");
      if(operationgain4="gain position") sendEmail(operationgain4);
        function sendEmail(operationgain4) {
          var email = "adrian@semeniuk.biz";
          var subject = "Your "+amount4+" "+coin4+" are somewhere in gain position.";
          var body = "Keep an eye on your "+coin4+"s, they're goin' up.";
          MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,body);}
      var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName("AutoMail"); 
      var operationgain5 = sheet1.getRange("K2:K46").getValue();
      var operationpurchase5 = sheet1.getRange("L2:L46").getValue();
      var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("YourData");
      var coin5 = sheet2.getRange("F3");
      var amount5 = sheet2.getRange("F4");
      if(operationgain5="gain position") sendEmail(operationgain5);
        function sendEmail(operationgain5) {
          var email = "adrian@semeniuk.biz";
          var subject = "Your "+amount5+" "+coin5+" are somewhere in gain position.";
          var body = "Keep an eye on your "+coin5+"s, they're goin' up.";
          MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,body);}
      var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName("AutoMail"); 
      var operationgain6 = sheet1.getRange("M2:M46").getValue();
      var operationpurchase6 = sheet1.getRange("N2:N46").getValue();
      var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("YourData");
      var coin6 = sheet2.getRange("G3");
      var amount6 = sheet2.getRange("G4");
      if(operationgain6="gain position") sendEmail(operationgain6);
        function sendEmail(operationgain6) {
          var email = "adrian@semeniuk.biz";
          var subject = "Your "+amount6+" "+coin6+" are somewhere in gain position.";
          var body = "Keep an eye on your "+coin6+"s, they're goin' up.";
          MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,body);}
      var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName("AutoMail"); 
      var operationgain7 = sheet1.getRange("O2:O46").getValue();
      var operationpurchase7 = sheet1.getRange("P2:P46").getValue();
      var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("YourData");
      var coin7 = sheet2.getRange("H3").getValue();
      var amount7 = sheet2.getRange("H4").getValue();
      if(operationgain7="gain position") sendEmail(operationgain7);
        function sendEmail(operationgain7) {
          var email = "adrian@semeniuk.biz";
          var subject = "Your "+amount7+" "+coin7+" are somewhere in gain position.";
          var body = "Keep an eye on your "+coin7+"s, they're goin' up.";
          MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,body);}
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this modification? But I worry about whether I could completely understand your question. If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. My understanding from your question is as follows.

- When the word of "gain position" is included in the cells of "O2:O46", you want to send an email with `var subject = "Your "+amount+" "+coin+" are somewhere in gain position."`.
- When the word of "purchase position" is included in the cells of "P2:P46", you want to send an email with `var subject = "Purchase position for your "+amount+" "+coin+" somewhere there!";`.
- `coin` and `amount` are used at `sendEmail()`.
- Is `sheet` used at `var operationpurchase = sheet.getRange("P2:P46").getValue();` `sheet1`? In this sample, I used `sheet1`.
- About `var coin = sheet2.getActiveCell("H3");` and `var amount = sheet2.getActiveCell("H4");`, I didn't know what you want to do. I'm sorry. So I estimated that you might want the values of "H3" and "H4".

The modified script which is reflected above is as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
function readCell() {
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName("AutoMail"); 
  var operationgain = sheet1.getRange("O2:O46").getValues(); // Modified
  var operationpurchase = sheet1.getRange("P2:P46").getValues(); // Modified
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("YourData");
  var coin = sheet2.getRange("H3").getValue(); // Modified
  var amount = sheet2.getRange("H4").getValue(); // Modified

  // Below script was added.
  var email, subject, body
  if (~Array.prototype.concat.apply([], operationgain).indexOf("gain position")) {
    email = "//my email here//";
    subject = "Your " + amount + " " + coin + " are somewhere in gain position.";
    body = "Keep an eye on your " + coin + "s, they're goin' up.";
  }
  if (~Array.prototype.concat.apply([], operationpurchase).indexOf("purchase position")) {
    email = "//my email here//";
    subject = "Purchase position for your " + amount + " " + coin + " somewhere there!";
    body = "Your " + coin + "s might be about to be sold, give them a look.";
  }
  if (email && subject && body) MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,body);
};
```

#### Note :

- `~Array.prototype.concat.apply([], operationpurchase).indexOf("purchase position")` means that the 2 dimensional array retrieved by `getValues()` is flattened, and the strings of `purchase position` is searched.

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: Hi Tanaike! Thanks a lot, your edits, though I noticed some of those same mistakes already, are useful. The "sheet.getRange" was "sheet1.getRange" of course and "getActiveCell" came up from a suggestion of the system when typing the code, then edited to "getRange" as well as you've done.

Now, I need to wait some time, since yesterday evening used all 101 emails available per day. The mailing system was repetitive, not only one notification, but one every minute (maybe must set better the trigger) and only regarding one, the last one, of the 7 operations.

Comment: I think, regarding the latter issue, that variables somehow overwrote themselves. I copy my actual code in a new answer. Each operation is now integrated in one readCell function.

Comment: @Adrian Semeniuk Thank you for posting your answer.

Comment: here you deserve the thanks for your disponibility ;) if you know the way to solve those still remaining issues please share it with me, I'm still stuck

Comment: @Adrian Semeniuk Although I had thought that you solved by yourself, I'm sorry I misunderstand it. About the remaining issues, can you update your question by including the detail information. It will help for many users to think of the solution for them. I think if the updated question is much difference from the initial question, the separation of question and the simpler question might lead to more quick solution. I apologize that the issues was remained because of my incomplete answer.

Answer (score 0):

So just to resume from my previous comments:
1. I received an email each minute, so the script checks the cell each minute and if in gain or purchase sends an email, would like it to check it once of course;
2. mailing regarded only the last operation, that one which variables have a 7 at the end;
3. I think ss1 and sheet1 don't need to be repeated for every operation, of course if all 7 remain integrated in one function... I still can make 7 different functions as for the first edition of the code and as for your previous reply.

```
function readCell() {
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName("AutoMail"); 
  var operationgain1 = sheet1.getRange("C2:C46").getValue();
  var operationpurchase1 = sheet1.getRange("D2:D46").getValue();
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("YourData");
  var coin1 = sheet2.getRange("B3");
  var amount1 = sheet2.getRange("B4");
  if(operationgain1="gain position") sendEmail(operationgain1);
    function sendEmail(operationgain1) {
      var email = "adrian@semeniuk.biz";
      var subject = "Your "+amount1+" "+coin1+" are somewhere in gain position.";
      var body = "Keep an eye on your "+coin1+"s, they're goin' up.";
      MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,body);}
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName("AutoMail"); 
  var operationgain2 = sheet1.getRange("E2:E46").getValue();
  var operationpurchase2 = sheet1.getRange("F2:F46").getValue();
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("YourData");
  var coin2 = sheet2.getRange("C3");
  var amount2 = sheet2.getRange("C4");
  if(operationgain2="gain position") sendEmail(operationgain2);
    function sendEmail(operationgain2) {
      var email = "adrian@semeniuk.biz";
      var subject = "Your "+amount2+" "+coin2+" are somewhere in gain position.";
      var body = "Keep an eye on your "+coin2+"s, they're goin' up.";
      MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,body);}
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName("AutoMail"); 
  var operationgain3 = sheet1.getRange("G2:G46").getValue();
  var operationpurchase3 = sheet1.getRange("H2:H46").getValue();
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("YourData");
  var coin3 = sheet2.getRange("D3");
  var amount3 = sheet2.getRange("D4");
  if(operationgain3="gain position") sendEmail(operationgain3);
    function sendEmail(operationgain3) {
      var email = "adrian@semeniuk.biz";
      var subject = "Your "+amount3+" "+coin3+" are somewhere in gain position.";
      var body = "Keep an eye on your "+coin3+"s, they're goin' up.";
      MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,body);}
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName("AutoMail"); 
  var operationgain4 = sheet1.getRange("I2:I46").getValue();
  var operationpurchase4 = sheet1.getRange("J2:J46").getValue();
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("YourData");
  var coin4 = sheet2.getRange("E3");
  var amount4 = sheet2.getRange("E4");
  if(operationgain4="gain position") sendEmail(operationgain4);
    function sendEmail(operationgain4) {
      var email = "adrian@semeniuk.biz";
      var subject = "Your "+amount4+" "+coin4+" are somewhere in gain position.";
      var body = "Keep an eye on your "+coin4+"s, they're goin' up.";
      MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,body);}
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName("AutoMail"); 
  var operationgain5 = sheet1.getRange("K2:K46").getValue();
  var operationpurchase5 = sheet1.getRange("L2:L46").getValue();
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("YourData");
  var coin5 = sheet2.getRange("F3");
  var amount5 = sheet2.getRange("F4");
  if(operationgain5="gain position") sendEmail(operationgain5);
    function sendEmail(operationgain5) {
      var email = "adrian@semeniuk.biz";
      var subject = "Your "+amount5+" "+coin5+" are somewhere in gain position.";
      var body = "Keep an eye on your "+coin5+"s, they're goin' up.";
      MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,body);}
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName("AutoMail"); 
  var operationgain6 = sheet1.getRange("M2:M46").getValue();
  var operationpurchase6 = sheet1.getRange("N2:N46").getValue();
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("YourData");
  var coin6 = sheet2.getRange("G3");
  var amount6 = sheet2.getRange("G4");
  if(operationgain6="gain position") sendEmail(operationgain6);
    function sendEmail(operationgain6) {
      var email = "adrian@semeniuk.biz";
      var subject = "Your "+amount6+" "+coin6+" are somewhere in gain position.";
      var body = "Keep an eye on your "+coin6+"s, they're goin' up.";
      MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,body);}
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName("AutoMail"); 
  var operationgain7 = sheet1.getRange("O2:O46").getValue();
  var operationpurchase7 = sheet1.getRange("P2:P46").getValue();
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("YourData");
  var coin7 = sheet2.getRange("H3").getValue();
  var amount7 = sheet2.getRange("H4").getValue();
  if(operationgain7="gain position") sendEmail(operationgain7);
    function sendEmail(operationgain7) {
      var email = "adrian@semeniuk.biz";
      var subject = "Your "+amount7+" "+coin7+" are somewhere in gain position.";
      var body = "Keep an eye on your "+coin7+"s, they're goin' up.";
      MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,body);}
};
```